# Show records where team assignment = 1

Tags: sql

by changing the below TeamRecords = 1 to = another number finds the rows with the amount I change to, its only sometimes its counting one too many which is odd. When a new Incident is created it has a unique number and every time a new assignment is added from the Task table it adds another row of the IncidentNumber, so you could have duplicate Incident number rows which I've remove with the seq = 1 below. When a new assignment is created it creates a new CreateddateTime in the Task table so for example you could do a Max(t.[CreatedDateTime] to find the last assignment of any IncidentNumber. So, the TeamRecords = 1 is what I need to find all records for that specific team where there is only 1 assignment for that team.

Does that help any?
Here is what I have so far...

```
Use TEST
Go

  WITH RankResult AS
(   
SELECT  i.[IncidentNumber],
        i.[CreatedDateTime],
        i.[ResolutionDateAndTime],
        i.[Priority],
        i.[Status],
        i.[ClientName],
        i.[ClientSite],
        t.[OwnerTeam],
        t.[Owner],
            row_number() over( partition by i.RecID 
                        order by t.CreatedDateTime desc, t.OwnerTeam ) seq,
        TeamRecords = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ParentLink_RecID)
FROM    Incident as i
        Inner JOIN Task as t
            ON i.RecID = t.ParentLink_RecID
WHERE   t.OwnerTeam = 'Infrastructure Services'
AND     i.CreatedDateTime >= '20121001'
AND     i.CreatedDateTime <= '20131001'

)
SELECT  DISTINCT
    [IncidentNumber],
    [CreatedDateTime],
    [ResolutionDateAndTime],
    [Priority],
    [Status],
    [ClientName],
    [ClientSite],
    [OwnerTeam],
    [Owner]
FROM    RankResult
Where   TeamRecords = 1
And Seq = 1
Order By IncidentNumber Asc
GO
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: What's an "assignment"? What's a "team selection"?

Comment: Yes SQL Server an assignment is a task in the task table, so 1 assignmet = 1 task. There can be many tasks in the task table, so many assignments. There will always be only one IncidentNumber although it will repeat depending on how many assignments there are.

Comment: I meant for you to update your question. It's rather lacking in important details at the moment.

Comment: I've updated main topic now, thanks for help, the code works 99% of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a simple subquery which groups across the relevant columns, counts them, filters where the count is 1, then joins it back to the main table to select the appropriate rows:

```
SELECT      Incident.*
FROM        (
                SELECT      OwnerTeam
                FROM        Incident AS Inc1
                GROUP BY    OwnerTeam
                HAVING      COUNT( * ) = 1
            )   AS Team 
        ,   Incident
WHERE       Incident.OwnerTeam = Team.OwnerTeam
```

(Without more information, though, it's difficult to say if this will work for you.)

Comment: Should be `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Using ROW_NUMBER means you will return the first assignment per team, not necessarily the teams with only one assignment. To do this you can use `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
WITH RankResult AS
(   
    SELECT  i.[IncidentNumber],
            i.[CreatedDateTime],
            i.[ResolutionDateAndTime],
            i.[Priority],
            i.[Status],
            i.[ClientName],
            i.[ClientSite],
            t.[OwnerTeam],
            t.[Owner],
            TeamRecords = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY i.RecID)
    FROM    Incident as i
            INNER JOIN Task as t
                ON i.RecID = t.ParentLink_RecID
    WHERE   t.OwnerTeam = 'Info Services'
    AND     i.CreatedDateTime >= '20121001'
    AND     i.CreatedDateTime <= '20131001'

)
SELECT  DISTINCT
        [IncidentNumber],
        [CreatedDateTime],
        [ResolutionDateAndTime],
        [Priority],
        [Status],
        [ClientName],
        [ClientSite],
        [OwnerTeam],
        [Owner]
FROM    RankResult
WHERE   TeamRecords = 1;
```

2 things to note that I have changed in addition to the analytic function. Firstly I have changed your dates to the culture independant format `yyyyMMdd`, `yyyy-MM-dd` can still be ambiguous, so `2013-01-02` could be the 1st Feb or the 2nd Jan depending on your server/session settings. Secondly, Your where cluase was turning your join into an `INNER JOIN` anyway, so I just made it an `INNER JOIN`:

```
    FROM    Incident as i
            LEFT JOIN Task as t
                ON i.RecID = t.ParentLink_RecID
    WHERE   t.OwnerTeam = 'Info Services'
    AND     i.CreatedDateTime >= '20121001'
```

Here, if there is no match in `Task` then `OwnerTeam` will be `NULL` and `NULL = 'Info Services'` evaluates to false, so you will never return any rows with no match in `Task` thus making it an INNER JOIN). If you did in fact want a LEFT JOIN then you need to move this clause to the JOIN:

```
    FROM    Incident as i
            LEFT JOIN Task as t
                ON i.RecID = t.ParentLink_RecID
                AND t.OwnerTeam = 'Info Services'
    WHERE   i.CreatedDateTime >= '20121001'
```

Comment: Agh wow I wasn't far away then :) this looks good and has reduced the number of records which I would expect. On checking the records I only see a few IncidentNumbers now with 2 instances of the same team which is strange? I should only see records with the 1 assignment per 1 team selection...can you advise? thanks

Comment: I suspect you are using the wrong column within `PARTITION BY`, try with `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.[OwnerTeam])`

Comment: That returns 0 rows although it made sense what you said, I tried changing to t.ParentLink_RecID but this returned the same as i.RecID.

Comment: How do you uniquely identify a team and an assignment? Some sample data and an expected output would be very helpful here.

Comment: There will be a new CreatedDateTime in the Task table created for each new assignment, it is the ParentLink_RecID that joins to the Incident RecID. I tried using the t.CreatedDateTime from the Task table but I still see the record with 2 for same team.

Comment: Its tricky to show actual results as I need to check the tickets to see if there is more than one instance for the team attached to an Incident. How do you add output, these comments make a mess of it?

Comment: Ok I have changed the Where   TeamRecords = 1 to = 2,3,4,5,6...and it seems to return the correct number of rows most of the time and showing records with the number I select, so the code is working although something is throwing the count on a few records which is baffling me.